# Failed building wheel for pymssql

Tags: docker

I need some help, with an app I'm trying to run in a docker conteiner, I'm receiving this error with pymssql package anyone know what's happening

> error: subprocess-exited-with-error
>
> × Building wheel for pymssql (pyproject.toml) did not run
> successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [25 lines of output]
> setup.py: platform.system() => Linux
> setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('64bit', 'ELF')
> setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('glibc', '2.31')
> setup.py: include_dirs => []
> setup.py: library_dirs => []
> running bdist_wheel
> running build
> running build_py
> creating build
> creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
> creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/pymssql
> copying src/pymssql/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/pymssql
> running build_ext
> cythoning src/pymssql/_mssql.pyx to src/pymssql/_mssql.c
> cythoning src/pymssql/_pymssql.pyx to src/pymssql/_pymssql.c
> building 'pymssql._mssql' extension
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src/pymssql
> gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python3.11 -c src/pymssql/_mssql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src/pymssql/_mssql.o -DMSDBLIB
> src/pymssql/_mssql.c:747:10: fatal error: sqlfront.h: No such file or directory
> 747 | #include "sqlfront.h"
> |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
> compilation terminated.
> error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
> [end of output]
>
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
> problem with pip.   ERROR: Failed building wheel for pymssql Failed to
> build pymssql ERROR: Could not build wheels for pymssql, which is
> required to install pyproject.toml-based projectsenter code here
>
> [notice] A new release of pip available: 22.2.2 -> 22.3 [notice] To
> update, run: pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: You forgot to share any details, like the code neccessary to reproduce the problem

Comment: You forgot to share any details, like the code neccessary to reproduce the problem

Comment: I managed to solve my problem with a python:latest